# How to delete a folder that's already in the Trash that's recursevily copying itself inside itself?

Tags: macos, file, infinite-loop, recycle-bin

I noticed there's a directory that I cannot delete from the trash because it says it's "in use". When I saw what's inside I found that there's an apparent infinite number of subdirectories inside named like the main one.

This is what I see.

Trash > T04 > T04 > T04 > T04 > T04 .... and so on

How can I stop this an delete everything? Besides having itself inside itself they are empty.

I'm using a mac.

Comment: ⌥⇧⌘⌫ (Empty trash with ⌥ key) does not work?

Comment: no, I tried that and did't work.

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that some task is using this directory.
To check if a task is using this directory use

```
lsof | grep "T04"
```

In case there is any result then find the process and kill the process. After this you could delete the directory normal.

Hope it helped!

Answer (score -1):

I think I fixed it. Using Terminal I did

cd .Trash/

rm -r T04

and I think it worked. Does anyone know for sure if that was the way to do it? I did I do something I don't know that might not really solve the problem? 
It just makes me uneasy thinking that there's a file copying itself infinitely and I can't stop it xd